# When client sends a message to server, the message gets truncated

Tags: java, sockets, packet

I'm new to multithreading. Im trying to do sending of messages between a client and a server. When I send a message to the server, my output in the server is supposed to be "Aji Computer: Thanks! :D", but instead I get a truncated data "Aji Computer: Thank".

Server code

```
    public QuoteServerThread(String name) throws IOException {
super(name);
socket = new DatagramSocket(4445);

 byte[] buf = new byte[256];
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);

in.close();

socket.receive(packet);

String dString = "Wassup " + packet.getAddress().getHostName() + "!";
//if (in == null) dString = new Date().toString();
//else dString = getNextQuote();
buf = dString.getBytes();
InetAddress address = packet.getAddress();
int port = packet.getPort();
packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, address, port);
socket.send(packet);

//THIS IS WHERE IM SUPPOSE TO PRINT "Aji Computer: Thanks! :D". But it prints out wrongly
packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
socket.receive(packet);
String received = new String(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength());
System.out.println(received);   
socket.close();
```

Client code

```
   DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
    byte[] buf = new byte[256];
    InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("Aji Computer");
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, address, 4445);
    socket.send(packet);
    packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
    socket.receive(packet);
    String received = new String(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength());
    System.out.println("Server: " + received);

    //THIS IS WHERE I SENT MY "Aji Computer: Thanks! :D" PACKET TO SERVER.
    buf = new byte[256];
    String str = "Aji Computer: Thanks! :D";
    buf = str.getBytes();
    packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, address, 4445);
    socket.send(packet);
    socket.close();
```

}

Just to let you know, this code is from Oracle. I modified a bit so that I would know how it works.

Comment: Please take the time to write in complete sentences.

Comment: Also, this is not related to multithreading.

Comment: Oops. sry. Ive got bad english. oh its not multi threading? Im sry. I assumed that when multiple clients connect to 1 server, thats multithreading. Thanks for the edit. Much Appreciated.

Comment: Bad english is not a problem here (there are plenty of people willing to help with that!), but saying things like "every1" and "Juz" and "msg" make it sound like you don't care enough about the reader to type the actual word, even though you know what the actual word is. StackOverflow is not your average internet forum, so please be sure to read the FAQ. Welcome to the site!

Comment: Multithreading is running concurrent operations (i.e. multiple threads) on a single computer. What you're talking about is socket communication. While servers very often employ multithreading to handle multiple clients, your question doesn't actually have anything to do with that aspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reassign the size of your byte array from 256 bytes to: `buf = dString.getBytes();` And further down in the program you created a new packet to receive on using `packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);` This uses the length of `dString.getBytes()` instead of `byte[256]` I am assuming that `dString.getBytes()` has less space than "Aji Computer: Thanks!"

Try reassigning your byte array to its original value:

```
buf = new byte[256];
```

**EDIT:** removed 'byte' from above

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion. But invoking 'byte[] buf = new byte[256];' again will cause an error. As it is already defined at the top of the code.

Comment: @user: remove `byte[] ` from it and it will compile.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, i didnt think that would be unclear, ill edit above.

Comment: Fixed it. Thanks Alot Hunter McMillen and Adam! Stackoverflow is really awesome!